# If $\phi:R\to S$ is an injective ring homomorphism, then is $\phi(R)\cong R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

> If $\phi:R\to S$ is an injective ring homomorphism, then is $\phi(R)\cong R$?

I cannot find anything like this anywhere, and it looks like it can be true. Just define $\psi:R\to \phi(R)$ by $\psi(r)=\phi(r)$. However, I could be wrong...

Comment: If $f:A \to B$ is any injective function, it is easy to show that $f$ is a bijection between $A$ and $f(A)$.

Comment: If you want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems

Comment: ie. ring isomorphism is the same as bijective ring homomorphism